# Changing the content of an pointer array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, global-variables

I am using c++ and needed a global array. So I used pointer array and declared it globally so that it can be accessible from all other local functions.

```
//GLOBAL VARIABLES
int **xArr;
int tmp=0;

myLocalFunc(){

    int c;

    for(c=0;c<5;c++){
       printf("%d ", xArr[c]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    for(c=0;c<5;c++){
        tmp++;
       *xArr[c] = tmp;
    }
}     


int main(){

    int c,i=0;

    xArr = new int*[5];

    for(c=0;c<5;c++){
      printf("X : ");
      scanf("%d",&xArr[c]);
    } 

    while(i<4){
       myLocalFunc();
       i++;
    }

}
```

What I understand is that myLocalFunc should display the 5 values of the xArr array that was set by the user in the main function. But then the values should be overwritten in the xArr array by the value of tmp variable. So if the user provided values are 99,100,101,102,103 then the output I am expecting is:

99 100 101 102 103
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15

The programs runs but it gives me wrong values in the xArr array after 99 100 101 102 103 line in the output. How can I fix the value assignment in the pointer?

Comment: Fixing code on the go? Don't do things like `int c, i;`. Declare them inside the loops.

Comment: You say that `xArr` is an array of five pointers to `int`, and then you use `scanf` passing `&xArr[c]`, where `xArr[c]` is an uninitialized pointer to `int`, so `&xArr[c]` is a pointer to an uninitialized pointer to `int` (type `int**`). This will lead to *undefined behavior*. Are you sure you want an array of *pointers* to `int`?

Comment: And if you're programming in C++, don't use the old unsafe C functions. Use C++ streams. If you want to read an `int` from standard input use `std::cin >> my_int_variable`

Comment: This looks like 70s-80s pre-standard C with `new`.

Comment: And calling `myLocalFunc()` four times in a row will overwrite the same five elements over and over. Also 4 * 5 = 20, not 16.

Comment: Why are you using pointers here at all? A `std::vector<int>` would be a better choice.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ,  i'm not allowed to use any thing from STL in here.. that's why

Comment: @coder Then you aren't learning c++. You should quit that course.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  yes i am not.. its a graphics course.. i am using glut library.. the reason i asked this question like this is because i wanted to simplify it to the readers and focus on just one thing that i need to know in this case. I am guessing that if i paste the entire file it would be difficult to understand what i am asking in the first place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I used pointer array
>
> ```
> int **xArr;
> ```

To be pedantic with nomenclature, this does not declare an array. This declares a pointer to a pointer. Yes, later on this will point to an array of pointers, but still, the distinction is important to understand.

> ```
> scanf("%d",&xArr[c]);
> ```

Remember that `xArr` is `int**`. Therefore `xArr[c]` is a `int*`. You're letting the user initialize pointers to arbitrary memory addresses. This very rarely makes any sense. Later on, when you dereference these pointers:

> ```
> *xArr[c]
> ```

You get undefined behaviour, because those user initialized pointers (probably) didn't point to memory that was allocated.

> How can I fix the value assignment in the pointer?

Instead of letting the user give you an arbitrary pointer values, assign the pointer to some memory that you have allocated.